# Juniper begin: Can't assign protocol inet and ping point2point

Tags: juniper-junos

I just start on Juniper 's world, However, I stuck at begin.

I run Junos on GNS3 with very  simple topology like

(Junos1-me0)----------------------(me0-Junos2)

My config:

```
Junos1: set interfaces me0 unit 0 family inet address 10.10.10.1/30
Junos2: set interfaces me0 unit 0 family inet address 10.10.10.2/30
```

Junos1:

```
root> show interfaces terse

Interface               Admin Link Proto    Local                 Remote

cbp0                    up    up
demux0                  up    up
dsc                     up    up
em0                     up    up    <<// There is no em0.0 and protocol field
em1                     up    down
em2                     up    down
em3                     up    down
em4                     up    down
em5                     up    down
gre                     up    up
ipip                    up    up
irb                     up    up
lo0                     up    up
lo0.16384               up    up   inet     127.0.0.1           --> 0/0
lo0.16385               up    up   inet     128.0.0.4           --> 0/0
                                   inet6    fe80::a00:270f:fc83:f167
lsi                     up    up
mtun                    up    up
pimd                    up    up
pime                    up    up
pip0                    up    up
pp0                     up    up
tap                     up    up

Junos2: 

root> show interfaces terse
Interface               Admin Link Proto    Local                 Remote
cbp0                    up    up
demux0                  up    up
dsc                     up    up
em0                     up    up    <<// There is no em0.0 and protocol field
em1                     up    up
em2                     up    down
em3                     up    down
em4                     up    down
em5                     up    down
gre                     up    up
ipip                    up    up
irb                     up    up
lo0                     up    up
lo0.16384               up    up   inet     127.0.0.1           --> 0/0
lo0.16385               up    up   inet     128.0.0.4           --> 0/0
                                   inet6    fe80::a00:270f:fc37:7cc4
lsi                     up    up
mtun                    up    up
pimd                    up    up
pime                    up    up
pip0                    up    up
pp0                     up    up
tap                     up    up
```

I can not ping p2p, The result as below:

```
Junos1> ping 10.10.10.2
PING 10.10.10.2 (10.10.10.2): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
^C
--- 10.10.10.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

Also, I tried to assign the other unit on the me0 interface, but it fail, The system info "Can not"

Anyone can help me fix this issue?

There is no route table on router

```
root> show route table ?
Possible completions:
  <table>              Name of routing table



 root> show route table inet.0
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Which interfaces did you link in GNS3?

Usually the em interfaces are used. You won't have unit 0 defined by default.

Move your interfaces from me0 to em0 on the respective devices. This is assuming that your GNS3 links are setup to map em0 on both devices as a connected link.

set interface em0 unit 0 family inet address x.x.x.x/x

Usually with Junos Olive\GNS3 you will not use ME0... the only interfaces that should be used are emX or fxpX depending on what kind of emulated interface you're using. Ideally if you use Intel Pro MT series then emX interfaces will appear.

If you have no active interfaces or routes then no table will exist, default Junos behaviour.

Comment: I used em0 both side,

I just fixed it by re-install Junos OS on VM.

Thank you for your comment.